# How to change color of text inside a GridView Textbox when GridView CheckBox is checked using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

How to change color of text inside a GridView Textbox when GridView CheckBox is checked using Javascript.

So When my gridview checkbox is checked I need it to check if the corresponding textbox is empty or not. If it is not empty then I need the text inside the gridview textbox to change color. This is what I have so far.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvSpecReq" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3"
                        EmptyDataText="No Records Found" Width="730" DataKeyNames="RID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Spec. Requirement" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelSpecReqText" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpecReqText" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReqText")%>'
                            Columns="45" Rows="4" onclick="blankSReq()" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkSpecReq" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelSpecReqNotes" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpecReqNotes" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReqNotes")%> '
                    Columns="25" Rows="4" onclick="blankSReq()" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkSpecReq" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelCheckBox" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSpecReq" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("isActive")%>' OnCheckedChanged="chkSpecReq_CheckedChanged" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

function blankSReq() {

    var form = document.forms[0]

    var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= gvSpecReq.ClientID %>');
    for (var i = 1; i < gridView .rows.length; i++) {

        var checkbox = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('checkbox');
        var textbox = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('textbox');
        var textboxnotes = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('textbox');

        {

        if (checkbox != null && checkbox.length > 1 && checkbox[0] != null && areas != null && textbox.length > 1 && textbox[0] != null) {
            if (textbox[1].type == "textbox" && checkbox[0].type == "checkbox") {
                var txtval = textbox[1].value;


                if (!checkbox[0].checked && (txtval == "" || txtval == null)) {
                    alert("There's nothing in the Special Requirement " + i + " field!")
                    (!checkbox[0].checked == false)
                }

                if (!checkbox[0].checked && (txtval !== "")) {
                    textbox.style.color = "rgb(150,150,150)"
                    textboxnotes.style.color = "rgb(150,150,150)"
                }
                else {
                    textbox.style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)"
                    textboxnotes.style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I checked your code and found that there is something missing. Can you edit your code again. I think you can achieve what you want through css, but still update your code, I will take a look and figure out what to do.

Comment: I added the entire Gridview if this helps at all. Also Id much rather do it through JavaScript. Or a combination of both

Comment: Please try to call blankSReq() function on checkbox checked event.